# Can a Google Apps Script Web App be scalable?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, concurrency

I'm developing a Google Apps Script Web App. This web app is the next version of FlipVideo, a script that I previously developed in a Google Sheet (see version at https://sites.google.com/view/flipvideo/)

This is a school oriented web app. A lot of students will access at the same time from around the world (thousands probably). I'm worried about scalability and quota limits.

I will publish the web app using "Execute the apps as: user accessing the web app" and "Who has access the app: anyone". Could this configuration allow thousands of concurrently executions or there is a hard quota impossible to scale?

Comment: This information is not for a web app, but I thought I'd mention it.  I looked at your site, and I notice that the user can make a copy of a spreadsheet.  If the code is running from a spreadsheet that they own, then any quota limit goes against their account.  Also, if you published the code as a Sheets add-on, then every account that installed the add-on has it's own quota limit.  And even though you are the owner of the script file, none of the quota goes against your account.  You could have millions of users of your add-on, and not have any quota limit against your account.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, what you require is not currently possible. GAS Web Apps have a max of 30 concurrent users ([see simultaneous executions under current limitations on the quotas page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)). You'll need to leverage a different solution to operate at such a large scale. If you want to stick with Google's Cloud Platform I would recommend using [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/). However, its not a free service.

Comment: Thank you Dimu... I thought there was a way to bypass quota limits or pay without using Cloud Platform Products :(

Comment: Isn't it 30 executions **per user**?

Answer (score 0):

> There are too many scripts running simultaneously for this Google user
> account. This indicates that you have too many scripts executing at
> once, although not necessarily the same script. Like the exception
> above, this most commonly occurs for custom functions that are called
> repeatedly in a single spreadsheet.

This above limitation means a single user cannot have the same script executing 30 times. For example, you can achieve this limit by opening the same web app in 30 different tabs. So I guess the limit on the number of users does not exist, or else App Script would lose all meaning as an IDE.

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct it a little. If you just open the webapp in more than 30 tabs, it will not lead to an error. But if you open a webapp containing the onOpen function in more than 30 tabs simultaneously, an exception will occur. But it will be "Exception: Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets at onOpen (Code: 13: 8)", not "Exception: Too many simultaneous executions".